# jQuery mousewheel plugin from Github won't install

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to install the mousewheel plugin from jQuery so I can use mousewheel movements to fire a function. I've got the following code:

```
<script src="https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel.git"></script>

<script>

$(window).mousewheel(function(turn, delta) {

  if (delta == 1) // going down
  else //going up

  // all kinds of code

  return false;
});

</script>
```

This just returns the error

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://github.com/jquery/jquery-
mousewheel.git' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, 
and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

What is stopping the Github file from installing? Consequently, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mousewheel is not a function
```

Apologies in advance if this is a ridiculous question, I'm very new to coding and I don't have a clue why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the JavaScript from github and reference that file instead of the .git

Here's your github link https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel?files=1

Download jquery.mousewheel.js and reference that downloaded file.

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded the file, placed it in my website directory and referenced it there. It works great! I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.